# How to declare a List<> in Dart correctly?

Tags: json, list, dart

i'm having a problem do declare a List<> in Dart.

Here is my code:

```
final lockers = List<Locker>();

for (Map map in listaResponse) {
      Locker l = Locker.fromJson(map);
      lockers.add(l);
}
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image: What could be de cause?]

I have no idea about what could possibly be the cause for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The zero-argument version of the `List` constructor is deprecated when null-safety is enabled.  From its [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/List/List.html):

> NOTICE: This constructor cannot be used in null-safe code. Use `List.filled` to create a non-empty list. This requires a fill value to initialize the list elements with. To create an empty list, use `[]` for a growable list or `List.empty` for a fixed length list (or where growability is determined at run-time).

In your case, you should use a literal:

```dart
final lockers = <Locker>[];
```